# why is swiftmailer shipped with symfony2 by default?

Tags: symfony

What part of Symfony2 needs Swiftmailer?

It's not used by the demo-controllers.

I am wondering b/c I am trying to figure out how to put Symfony2 on a diet without inhibiting the administration / debug interface.

Is it just for marketing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not for Marketing. Symfony2 uses Swiftmailer as a mail sending library. If you don't plan to send any mails within your application, you might try to remove SwiftMailer from the vendors.

Comment: where does Symfony2 use Swiftmailer? And if it does, I cannot just remove it, as Symfony2 uses it ... but if it doesn't really ... then it is marketing. Cause for what else reason do you ship a bundle like Swift with the **standard** distribution if it is not actually used?!

Comment: This is because most of the people will want to send mails in their applications.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter too quickly.  SwiftMailer is only used by the SwiftMailerBundle. You can remove it and swiftmailer from the vendor safely if you do NOT plan to send mails.

Comment: that is an answer. 

Are you involved in symfony2 development? I wonder why the "official" symfony2 board is almost dead. How come?

Comment: I have no idea. You might try the google group also: http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2?lnk=srg

Comment: thanks. this looks more vibrant on first glance!

Comment: I'm a moderator for the Symfony forum. There is nothing untoward about it being relatively quiet there - drumming up a vibrant community around a good product can still be quite difficult. And as @futurecat says, there are a number of google groups for symfony usage and development. It has been suggested in the past that Symfony 2 has attracted more high-end developers who are less likely to need help. But, whatever the reason, more active helpers on the board are very welcome to join!

Comment: In terms of the original question, I'd say most developers will want the functionality offered by Swiftmailer. But for devs who do not need it, I should think it would be safe to remove.

Comment: Actually, you can remove almost anything from Symfony 2, if you don't plan on using it. Symfony 2 framework is made from decoupled bundles.